# How do I delete old shelvesets from TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

Visual Studio 2017's "Find Shelvesets" TFS command displays:

> Results (showing 100 of 392)

How do I access the other 292 items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use the commandline to list them all:

```
tf vc shelvesets
```

And

```
tf vc shelve /delete
```

to delete one.

Or download the [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) which provides a dedicated UI for a number of clean-up actions, including old shelvesets.

Comment: TFS SideKicks is nice but it does not allow multiple item deletion at once. Should I repeat the same operation three hundreds of times?

Comment: Long time since I've used it... Last time I had to clean up an instance I used `tf vc shelvesets` to grab all the names of the shelvesets and then built the 300 `tf vc shelve /delete` statements though notepad/excel/yourfavoriteeditor. Then ran that from the commandline.